# Moving Row to another sheet and clear content/ ArrayFormula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

**Short story:**
How do I modify the script below to clear contents in multiple cells in the row? For example Rows 7,13,24,25,34

**Long story (in case there is a better solution):**

I have been using this script to move rows between sheets based on a value without carrying over the formatting so the next sheet has its own and the conditional formatting isn't stacking up.

```
  function onEditComplete(e) {
 //e.source.toast('Entry');
 //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
 const sh=e.range.getSheet();
 if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1a" && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.value=="Completed") {
  //e.source.toast('Conditional');
 var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2a");
 tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()). 
getValues());
sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);}
  }
```

The problem I am encountering now is I am using Formulas.
I have 4 sheets. **Sheet1a** and **Sheet1b** have vlookup formulas between them. **Sheet2a** and **Sheet2b** will also have the same Vlookup formula between them.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(PARTS!$B1:$B,{PARTS!$B1:$B,PARTS!$AF1:$BD&","&PARTS!$AJ1:$AJ&","&PARTS!$AN1:$AN&","&PARTS!$AR1:$AR&","&PARTS!$AV1:$AV&","&PARTS!$AR1:$AR&","&PARTS!$AZ1:$AZ},2,0)))
```

Since it's an ArrayFormula, as long as **Sheet2a** and **Sheet2b** are set it should only be a matter of clearing the content in the specific cells before it moves over since it transfers as text value and breaks the formula in **Sheet2a** and **Sheet2b**.

Comment: Sorry, but still I don't understand what's your end objective and where exactly you're having problem. can you explain that by giving some example scenarios?

Comment: Could you provide a sanitized copy of the sheet?

Comment: @Emel I'm gonna be honest with you, trying to put together a sanitized copy got me confused too. I went with an alternative solution to my problem all together so I'm lost. I overcomplicated my explanation with what I was trying to achieve. The simplest way to put it is, this script allows me to  `copy` and `delete` any row where a specific value is entered. When it lands on the next tab it has been stripped of format. I was looking for a way to clear the values of certain columns in the same selected row being copied and deleted. I hope that made more sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Even if you don't share a full copy of your Google Sheet, try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: @Emel here is a simplified copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10eZ-CcokHf1wRFHrOvzE2ASFySgiVWMqQ_fA2xM-ek4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When you hit `SEND` it moves to **FRUITS2** and when it lands it ruins the `arrayformula` in columns **C** and **F** so if I were to hit **SEND** in **FRUITS** Row 2 I need to clear content of cells **C2** and **F2** before it lands on **FRUITS2** and if I hit **SEND** on row 17 I would need the same thing to happen with **C17** and **F17**

Comment: All good Emel. The script below that Cooper shared works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding the ability to clear some cells in rows 7,13,24,25,34

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value == "Completed") {
    e.source.toast('Conditional');
    let cols = [7, 13, 24, 25, 34];
    let row = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().map((e, i) => {
      if (~cols.indexOf(i + 1)) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return e;
      }
    })
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setValues([row]);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies I don't think I explained it completely. This edit works but it clears the fixed cells specified in the edit. I am trying to clear the cell content of columns 7,13,24,25,34 in the row being moved before they land in the next tab.

Comment: Nevermind! Not sure what I did the first time but looking at it again I decided to try it out, it does work